# How Do I filter a specific month from a calendar dashboard?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a table containing information from 7 suppliers. Name, quantity of services requested, quantity of services done, location, type and date of the services.

The table considers the period from January 1st up today and I need to prepare a report showing in a graphic the quantity of services received from each supplier per month.

I´ve tried to do filter the month of march with:

```
CALCULATE(AVERGE(MY SPREADSHEET[DATE COLUMN]),
          DATESBETWEEN(MY SPREADSHEET [DATE COLUMN],
                       MAX(MY SPREADSHEET[DATE COLUMN])-29,
```

When I put -29 days I was trying to filter 29 days before today to filter march only, but it didn´t work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To filter on a month, -29 isn't repeatable. The normal approach is to create a date table and then a relationship between the date table and your data table. Then you use the month column from the date table to filter your data.

There's lot online about date tables in DAX. I'd start here:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/creating-a-simple-date-table-in-dax/